# Loading Twig extensions via TwigBridge in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, twig

I want to use the `truncate` filter from the Twig-extensions package in Laravel via TwigBridge, but I keep seeing this error:

```
The filter "truncate" does not exist in "[template file]" at line [##].
```

I tried adding the extension to `laravel/app/config/packages/rcrowe/twigbridge/config.php` extensions array several different ways, none worked.

```php
'Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text',
```

and

```php
function () {
    return new Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text();
},
```

Composer installed the file correctly, I was able to load it from a test file using the same autoloader.

What configuration settings are needed to get TwigBridge to load this extension?

Answer (score 4):

Well, I feel a little dumb, but let's make the most of it. Here's an excessively explicit walkthrough of how to enable additional Twig extensions for [TwigBridge](https://github.com/rcrowe/TwigBridge) in Laravel.

**TL;DR:** Extensions are configured in `extensions.php`, not `config.php`.

**Composer**

Start here. Either use Composer's require CLI command; `composer require twig/extensions` or add the following line to your **composer.json** file.

```
"twig/extensions": "1.2.*@dev",
```

If you modify composer.json, be sure to run `composer update` so the package installs.

**Configuring TwigBridge**

To add Twig extensions to TwigBridge, they must be added to the `enabled` array in `laravel/app/config/packages/rcrowe/twigbridge/extensions.php`. Not `config.php`. Even though there might be an extensions array in `config.php` and it's where everything else is configured, that's not where extensions are enabled. This is spelled out in TwigBridge's documentation, but it's easy to overlook. I managed to miss it several times.

```
'enabled' => [
    'TwigBridge\Extension\Loader\Facades',
    'TwigBridge\Extension\Loader\Filters',
    // ...
    'Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text',   // <- add this
],
```

TwigBridge's documentation refers to a `config.php` file but the configuration file seems to have been renamed to `twig.php` a while back. Generating a fresh configuration with `artisan config:publish rcrowe/twigbridge` yielded `twig.php` and `extensions.php` files -- no `config.php`. I've been using TwigBridge for a while so I still had one laying around, probably adding to my confusion.

**Extension Names**

The name of each extension can be found in the extension file--they're just Train_Case class names. As of January 2015, the [Twig-extensions project](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig-extensions) contained five extensions, listed here with their included filters:

- **Array** - `Twig_Extensions_Extension_Array`
  filters: `shuffle`
- **Date** - `Twig_Extensions_Extension_Date`
  filters: `time_diff`
- **I18n** - `Twig_Extensions_Extension_I18n`
  filters: `trans`
- **Intl** - `Twig_Extensions_Extension_Intl`
  filters: `localizeddate`, `localizednumber`, `localizedcurrency`
- **Text** - `Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text`
  filters: `truncate`, `wordwrap`